# No module named 'pydruid'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, druid, pydruid

I'm following this tutorial from [Druid](https://druid.apache.org/blog/2014/04/15/intro-to-pydruid.html) which is to connect jupyter notebook to druid. When i ran it keep giving me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydruid'` when i already installed the requirement.

Comment: Just do 'pip freeze' to check package is installed in your python version. Make sure you installed in correct python version

Comment: @NarendraPrasath from ```pip freeze``` it does show pydruid==0.6.0 . which is the correct latest version

Comment: Have you tried restarting your kernal and do import.

Comment: Yes i've tried restart kernal. I even tried changing environment to python 2.7 @NarendraPrasath

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like pydruid 0.6.0 has this issue. Try installing the previous version of pydruid.

`pip install pydruid==0.5.9` for workaround. Refer [here](https://github.com/druid-io/pydruid/issues/220) for the same issue in github.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Narendra Prasath issue has been resolve as per you suggestion

Comment: @DzakirinResearch, this issue has been solved in pydruid==0.6.1 version.  Check official repo here https://github.com/druid-io/pydruid/issues/220#issuecomment-643107735